# C# Writing large files (4GB +)

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, large-files

I'm still relatively new to C# and am fiddling around within a bigger project, which is not really mine. I just use it to fool around and learn a bit.

In that project there is an mp4 video being streamed via a BufferedStream inside a StreamWriter.
At this point I can essentially use the same logic to write the contents that would go into the BufferedStream into a FileStream and save it as a file that way. The streams are defined in a different function.

That worked fine until I came across a larger file. At a certain size (4.194.300 KB according to the Windows Explorer) the writing stops.

I've been googling around quite a bit, but I haven't really found any solution to writing such large files.

Does anyone have any ways or tips to get around this issue?

I added the this._filestream lines and there is some complexer stuff happening in the GetCount function deeper in the code, but that shouldn't be relevant. I had also tried to throw the FileStream inside of a StreamWriter as well, but without success, not that I expected a lot of success there.

```
public void Process()
{
    this._outputStream = new StreamWriter(new BufferedStream(this._tcpClient.GetStream()));
    this._fileStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
    try
    {
        this.HandleGetRequest(this._startByte, this._endByte, this._fileLength);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        this.WriteFailure();
    }
}
```

```
public void HandleGetRequest(long startByte, long endbyte, long fileLength)
{
    try
    {
        // Output Meta removed for conciseness
        this._outputStream.AutoFlush = true;
        byte[] array = new byte[1048575];
        for (;;)
        {
            long count = this.controller.GetCount(startByte, array, array.Length);
            if (count == 0L)
            {
                break;
            }
            startByte += count;
            this._outputStream.BaseStream.WriteAsync(array, 0, (int)count, this._cancellationToken).Wait(this._cancellationToken);
            this._fileStream.WriteAsync(array, 0, (int)count, this._cancellationToken).Wait(this._cancellationToken);
        }
        this._outputStream.BaseStream.Flush();
        this._outputStream.AutoFlush = false;
        this._fileStream.Flush();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What file system type are you writing to? FAT or FAT32?

Comment: My standard SSD; NTFS formatted.

Comment: Why do you create a `StreamWriter` around your buffered stream if you're only ever gonna use the stream directly? Also, if you're gonna do synchronous I/O anyway, use `Write`, not `WriteAsync`.

Comment: It's not my program initially. It's all part of a bigger thing and it plays the video in a player. I just want to dump it as well. Doesn't need to make sense right now . Though I think the size limit is not related to it being async to begin with.

Comment: It's just a very bad idea to wait on tasks and will usually lead to things like deadlocks

Comment: Agreed, change this to fully `async` code and let's see what happens. `catch (Exception){}` is also a bad idea, it's just going to swallow any exception without any logging

Comment: As a side note, using a try-finally block to call Dispose() method or applying the using block to ensure that your code calls Dispose() method